# SUM values from SQL column from same ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, schema.org

This is the comment_meta from wordpress. In there is a custom meta_key: rating.

I would like to get the SUM of all the ratings for that individual post.

The point being of this is to get the average from the user ratings. I have the total number of commenters, I just need the SUM.

The use of it is for the Schema.org AggregateReview: `<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content=""/>`.

I have tried to add the value via jQuery, but for some reason the schema isn't registering the text added later in the DOM.

```
var sum = 0;
$('.comment_rate').each(function(){
    numItems = $('.comment_rate').length
    sum += (parseFloat($(this).text()) / numItems);
    $('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').text(sum);
});
```

## ORIGINAL POST

I have this table (sorry, image is only way I know how to show):
[image]

I would like to sum the `meta_value` from the matching `comment_id`.

So far I have this but it SUMs the entire column not the ones matching the same id.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS value_sum FROM wp_play_commentmeta');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $sum = $row['value_sum'];
    echo $sum;
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT comment_id, SUM(meta_value) AS value_sum 
FROM wp_play_commentmeta
GROUP BY comment_id;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b32a6/1).

---

If you want to do this for only those that had `rating` metakey, then add that in the `WHERE` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT comment_id, SUM(meta_value) AS value_sum 
FROM wp_play_commentmeta
wHERE meta_key = 'rating'
GROUP BY comment_id;
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b32a6/2)

---

### Update:

`JOIN` the two tables, and `GROUP BY post_id`. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.post_id,
  SUM(m.meta_value) AS value_sum
FROM wp_play_commentmeta    AS m
INNER JOIN wp_play_comments AS p ON m.comment_ID = p.comment_Id
wHERE meta_key = 'rating'
GROUP BY p.post_id;
```

---

**Note that:** Please stop using `Mysql_*` extensions, they are deprecated. Furtheremore your code this way is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [**`PDO`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or prepared statements instead.

Comment: Yeah this would have worked but I totally neglected not being able to match the ratings, not the comment_id

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv - What do you mean? Isn't that what you are looking for? Can you please update your question and show me the expected results that you are looking for? thanks.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv - Do you mean, `SUM` only the `meta_value` for those that had the `meta_key` = `rating`??

Comment: I updated, hopefully it makes sense. Sorry, was a late realisation that original my question was stupid.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv The second query should give you what you are looking for, it should give you the sum or rating for each comment. Isn't this is what you want? Have you tried it?

Comment: The second query only returns the last rating value in the comment loop. I need the sum of all the rating values associated with that post.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv IS there any column that indicates to a specific post? I can't see any such column. Is there a `post_id` or any column relate to the post in this table? I only see `meta_id`, `comment_id`, `meta_key` and `meta_value`.

Comment: Not in this table. There is another table called `wp_play_comments` that has the `comment_post_ID` (matches the post ID) and the `comment_ID` that matches the id in the image.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv -  Why didn't you said that in your question? So they are related to each other by the `comment_id`? and the `post_id` is coming form the second table `wp_play_comments` or from a third table??

Comment: Coming from a second table, well I think it's the other way around: `wp_play_comments` -> `wp_play_commentmeta`

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv - You should loop through them. Something like `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result )){ echo $row['post_id']; echo $row['value_sum'];}`, But please try to avoid `mysql_*` extensions and use `PDO` instead, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

query will be

```
  SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS value_sum, comment_id FROM wp_play_commentmeta
  Group by comment_id
```